# after upgrading xcode - game with cocos2d not working: Property 'gameMode' not found on object of type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Game using cocos2d worked fine, But with this new xcode 4.3.3 is not working well.  It is showing this error:

```
Property 'gameMode' not found on object of type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'
```

in this part of the code:

```
-(void)oneDuckClicked:(id)sender{
    [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate].gameMode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OneDuck"];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] createDifficultySelectionScene];
}

-(void)twoDucksClicked:(id)sender{
    [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate].gameMode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TwoDucks"];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] createDifficultySelectionScene];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you simply need to cast your calls to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to the type of your application delegate. So, each time you make that call, cast the result like this:

```
((YourAppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

then you can call methods and access properties from your delegate:

```
((YourAppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).gameMode = 
    @"someGameMode";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add gameMode member in your appDelegate class.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject
{
    NSString *gameMode;
    …..
    …..
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyAchievement *Achievement;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize gameMode;

……..
……..
……..
@end
```

Access like this:

```
AppDelegate *App = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] ;
App.gameMode = @"MyGameMode";
```